(Unity 2D) Спрайт отображается поверх трейла, хотя трейл выше в Order In Layer
Есть у меня спрайт окружности, и по ней двигается игрок, а за этим игроком должен быть трейл. У трейла order in layer 1, а у окружности -1. Но при этом трейл почему то не видно.
Первый скриншот - окружность включена
Второй скриншот - окружность выключена


